# call a directive's function from a page using ng-click with angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How should I about calling a directive's function from a html page such as index, using ng-click? 
Here's my directive's code:

```
            $scope.moreText = function() {
                $(".showMore").append(lastPart);

            };
```

html:

```
<a ng-click='moreText()' class='showMore' href='#'>... show more</a>
```

My problem is that `moreText()` isn't being called when clicked. I understand that it's not the right $scope. but how do I access it?

Update:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('FormTestCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$window',
        function($scope, $timeout, $window) {


            $scope.moreText = function() {
               console.log("more text function***************");
                    $(".showMore").append(lastPart);
               };
        }
    ]);
```

Update: #2

Here is most of the directive:

```
    angular.module('myapp').directive('tooltip', function($window, $timeout) {

        return {

            restrict: 'A',
            replace: false,
            scope: {

                },

                link: function ($scope, element, attrs, $parse, $timeout) {

                    $scope.moreText = function() {};
                    $scope.sb = false;
                    var tooltext = attrs.tooltip;

    ...
                    if (tooltext.length > 10){
                        var firstPart = tooltext.substring(10, 0);
                        var lastPart = tooltext.substring(11, tooltext.length);

                        tooltext = firstPart + "<a ng-click='moreText()' class='showMore' href='#'>... show more</a>";
                    }

                   $scope.tipText = function(){
                        element.append("<div class='tooltip'>"+tooltext+"</div>");
                    };
                    $scope.moreText = function() {
                        console.log("more text function***************");


$(".showMore").append(lastPart);

                };

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Why are there two declarations of `$scope.moreText`?

Comment: See edit that i just posted

Comment: What does *" I understand that it's not the right $scope"* mean?

Comment: I understand that I cannot access my function through the `$scope`  because my html isn't inside the same `$scope`as my  `$scope.moreText`  function. So how can I go about accessing my moreText function from my index.html page?

Comment: Does the "tooltip" attribute get processed by some different directive or css style? Either way, i see that you created a "tooltext" variable, but this variable its not set back to a useful place, like scope or attrs.

Comment: I have another function (that I just added, see my edit) that I use to append the tool tip's text to, but didn't added it because I wanted to make the code easy to read and I didn't think it had anything to do with the problem.

Comment: Just adding/changing HTML on a element won't work. Angular will not detect the ng-click directive this way.

Comment: see if this plunker helps you in way. Its a minimal example on how to make a "show more" link. 
https://embed.plnkr.co/tbqRUWR7UINsu70jhQ7q/

You have to combine the scope variables with the directive template so that everything works out of the box. Else, if you have a more complicate scenario, you will have to use $compile or $parse providers.

Comment: oh, and the 'moreText ' function should be in the directive scope, not the controller... it is possible for a directive to call a function from the parent scope, or to pass to the directive a function to be called, but i think its not necessary in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just appending or changing the element html it´s not enough for angular to bind directives (like ngClick).

This plunk will give a base on how to recompile the HTML of the directive element:

https://embed.plnkr.co/t7qCM48dRyGmwHAZBffs/

The important bit:

```
element.html(html);
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

This will make angular aware of the ng-click or any new directives you want to insert into the element. I used a watcher, but its just as a sample. If you know your input parameters are not going to change you can get rid of the watcher.

Comment: I need my directive to only work as an attribute. Right now all I have to type is ` <div class="something" tooltip="This is a tooltip..">` any way I could add a "show more" to this attribute?

Comment: This plunker its doing that.  The difference its the directive name: in the plunker i called my-tooltip, but you can call just tooltip.
In the plunker i replaced the element text, but you can easily call some other method, like append a DIV with the full text. Now, about the "show more" text, this probably must be in the DIV you will show as tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a function you declared on your `$scope` you must nest the ng-click inside the controller that this `$scope` is part of.

For example:

```
myApp.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.moreText = function() {
       $(".showMore").append(lastPart);
   };
}]);

<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <a ng-click='moreText()' class='showMore' href='#'>... show more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: My function is inside a directive and get's the `lastPart` variable from other functions inside the directive, I'm assuming that placing the function inside the controller won't change anything? I also did what you said, but the moreText function is still not being called.

Comment: Here you go. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your directive's function out through a binding. e.g.

```
app.directive('tooltip', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      showMore: '='
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.showMore = function() {
        console.log('Show More!');
      };
    }
  };
})
```

And call it from outside the directive like this

```
<button ng-click="show()">Show More</button>
<div tooltip show-more="show"></div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Rs5d2wCtLzTJI8FNXb0h?p=preview